# Selecting from list by value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-lists

Suppose I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<b>Question 1: How do you feel today?</b>
<ul>
    <li id = '1'>happy</li>
    <li id = '2'>sad</li>
    <li id = '3'>angry</li>
</ul>

<b>Question 2: How does your dog feel today?</b>
<ul>
    <li id = '4'>happy</li>
    <li id = '5'>sad</li>
    <li id = '6'>angry</li>
</ul>
```

And then the following Jquery

```
emotion_id = $('li:contains('happy')).attr('id'))
```

How can I focus only pull from the Question 1 list? in this example, I want to set `emotion_id = 1`

Comment: It would only make the first match anyway. In other words, what you posted works (aside from the improper use of quotes)

Comment: is there a way to add a class to the ul tag? or il tag? and search for it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UL and LI Why not use

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var log = document.querySelector("#log");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var output = "";
  for (const entry of data) {
    output = output + entry[0] + "=" + entry[1] + "\r";
  };
  log.innerText = output;
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<form> 
  <p>Please select your preferred contact method:</p>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1"
           name="contact" value="email">
    <label for="contactChoice1">Email</label>
    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2"
           name="contact" value="phone">
    <label for="contactChoice2">Phone</label>
    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3"
           name="contact" value="mail">
    <label for="contactChoice3">Mail</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<pre id="log">
</pre>
```